# Mysql update a different field (column) for each id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that holds 
`PlayerID, goals, yellows,reds`
What I would like to do is increment the columns based on the playerID and the even (goal, yellow, red) in a single statement. Currently it is done one playerID at a time:

```
UPDATE players SET $event=$event+1 WHERE id=$playerID
```

where `$event` would hold the field name `(goals, yellows, reds)`

What I would like to do is have it all in a single statement. If you imagine player 1 got a yellow and player 2 got a red then I would picture the statement as:

```
UPDATE players SET (yellows=yellows+1,reds=reds+1) WHERE id=(1,2)
```

I know the above code is wrong but I hope it helps give an idea of what I would like to do. Each `SET` argument corresponds to the respective `id` argument.
Individually it would be:

```
  UPDATE players SET yellows=yellows+1 WHERE id=1
  UPDATE players SET reds=reds+1 WHERE id=2
```

I am **not** looking for:

```
UPDATE players SET (yellows=yellows+1,reds=reds+1) WHERE id IN (1,2)
```

Comment: While you can try doing this with a rather complex `if` function, what's wrong with using multiple `update`?

Comment: Nothing really, just wondered if there is a better way. With php mysql_query() how would I link the multiple UPDATES? Just with a comma at the end: mysql_querry("UPDATE players SET $event1=$event1+1 WHERE id=$playerID1,UPDATE players SET $event2=$event2+1 WHERE id=$playerID2")  ??

Comment: No, you'd simply execute multiple `mysql_query`: `mysql_query("UPDATE players SET $event1=$event1+1 WHERE id=$playerID1"); mysql_query("UPDATE players SET $event2=$event2+1 WHERE id=$playerID2");`

Comment: Thats what I thought. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE players 
SET yellows = CASE WHEN id = 1 
                     THEN yellows + 1
                     ELSE yellows
                   END  
  , reds    = CASE WHEN id = 2 
                     THEN reds + 1
                     ELSE reds 
              END
WHERE id IN (1, 2) ;
```